# Why does the pointfree version of this function look like this?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I've been playing around with Haskell a fair bit, including practising writing functions in point-free form. Here is an example function:

```
dotProduct :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
dotProduct xs ys = sum (zipWith (*) xs ys)
```

I would like to write this function in point-free form. Here is an example I found elsewhere:

```
dotProduct = (sum .) . zipWith (*)
```

However, I don't understand why the point-free form looks like `(sum .) . zipWith (*)` instead of `sum . zipWith (*)`. Why is sum in brackets and have 2 composition operators?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
dotProduct xs ys = sum (zipWith (*) xs ys)             -- # definition

dotProduct xs    = \ys -> sum (zipWith (*) xs ys)      -- # f x = g <=> f = \x -> g
                 = \ys -> (sum . (zipWith (*) xs)) ys  -- # f (g x) == (f . g) x
                 = sum . (zipWith (*) xs)              -- # \x -> f x == f
                 = sum . zipWith (*) xs                -- # Precedence rule

dotProduct       = \xs -> sum . zipWith (*) xs         -- # f x = g <=> f = \x -> g
                 = \xs -> (sum .) (zipWith (*) xs)     -- # f * g == (f *) g
                 = \xs -> ((sum .) . zipWith (*)) xs   -- # f (g x) == (f . g) x
                 = (sum .) . zipWith (*)               -- # \x -> f x == f
```

---

The `(sum .)` is a section. It is defined as

```
(sum .) f = sum . f
```

Any binary operators can be written like this, e.g. `map (7 -) [1,2,3] == [7-1, 7-2, 7-3]`.

Comment: Is the `*` in this part `f * g == (f *) g` the same as the `.` function composition?

Comment: @Bleu: Yes. Any binary operators will do.

Answer (score 14):

KennyTM's answer is excellent, but still I'd like to offer another perspective:

```
dotProduct = (.) (.) (.) sum (zipWith (*))
```

- `(.) f g` applies `f` on the result of `g` given one argument
- `(.) (.) (.) f g` applies `f` on the result of `g` given two arguments
- `(.) (.) ((.) (.) (.)) f g` applies `f` on the result of `g` given three arguments
- ...
- Can do `(.~) = (.) (.) (.)`, `(.~~) = (.) (.) (.~)`, `(.~~~) = (.) (.) (.~~)` and now `let foo a b c d = [1..5]; (.~~~) sum foo 0 0 0 0` results in `15`.

  - But I wouldn't do it. It will probably make code unreadable. Just be point-full.
- Conal's `TypeCompose` provides a synonym for `(.)` called `result`. Perhaps this name is more helpful for understanding what's going on.

  - `fmap` also works instead of `(.)`, if importing the relevant instances (`import Control.Applicative` would do it) but its type is more general and thus perhaps more confusing.
- Conal's concept of "fusion" (not to be confused with other usages of "fusion") is kind of related and imho offers a nice way to compose functions. More details in [this long Google Tech Talk that Conal gave](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faJ8N0giqzw)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still pretty new with Haskell, so some of this looks..arcane.. but learning about different approaches is helpful too :)

Comment: The `(.) (.) (.)` case is common and straightforward enough that I sometimes create a `(...)` operator for it. Beyond that, though, it's probably time to be pointful.